# in linux,how to create jar files with including external jars and log4j.propeties file using ant

Tags: ant, jar

i want to create jar file with external jars and log4j.properties file using ant.i am having only source code alone.
Please let me know how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple sketch to start with. You have to specify more details for us to give you a better answer, for example the project layout, the place where external jars and the log4j.properties file are.

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

  <path id='external.classpath'>
    <pathelement location='commons-io-1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.jar' />
  </path>

  <target name="build">

    <javac debug='true' debuglevel='source,lines,vars' destdir='project\temp' source='1.5' target='1.5' includeAntRuntime='false' encoding='utf-8'>
      <src path='src' />
      <classpath refid='external.classpath' />
    </javac>

   <jar jarfile='build\foobar.jar' basedir='project\temp' />

   <copy file='commons-io-1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.jar' todir='build'/>
   <copy file='log4j.properties' todir='build'/>

  </target>
</project>
```